# Почему скролл не опускается вниз?

Tags: html, css, javascript

Вот код, когда-то уже задавал вопрос, ответили, но при тесте не получается, объясните ошибку, пожалуйста

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Тест скролла</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1251">
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(window).load(function() {
window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div style="width: 500px; height: 1500px; border: 3px solid blue;"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(window).load(function() {
    $('html,body').scrollTop($(document).height());
});
```

[Пример работы](http://jsfiddle.net/Deonis/ktfpx/), или [анимированный вариант](http://jsfiddle.net/Deonis/ktfpx/1/)

Comment: У меня не работают скроллы при таком стилевом положении, что можно тут поправить?
.chat-content {
 background: url('../images/bg.png');
 width: 97%;
 height: 350px;
 border-right: 5px solid yellowgreen;
 border-left: 5px solid yellowgreen;
 box-shadow: 0 0 15px black;
 box-shadow: 0 0 15px rgba(160,82,45,0.7);
 margin: 0px;
 padding: 100px 10px 0px 10px;
 overflow: auto;
 position: fixed;
 z-index: 1;
}

Comment: Опишите свою задачу как-нибудь подробней. Не помешает, если выложите код (часть, относящуюся к данной проблеме) на jsfiddle.net

Comment: Спасибо, но скролл опускается лишь на немного вниз и все...

Comment: внутри блока еще вот такие с сообщениями
.message {
 border-radius: 50px;
 -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 3px #999;
 -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 3px #999;
 border-bottom: 1px solid #222;
 position: relative;
 left: 15px;
 margin: 0px 400px 15px 0px;
 padding: 10px 25px 10px 25px;
}

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте лучше 
<pre>$(document).ready(function() {
//Здесь код
});</pre>

Comment: куда это именно

Answer (score 0):

Лучше используйте скролл на чистом JS, т.к. на JQuery он довольно медленно работает (есть видимая задержка при скроллинге вниз):

```
el.scrollTop = Math.ceil(el.scrollHeight - el.clientHeight);
```

Где el - это страница или элемент, где требуется все промотать вниз, а округление нужно для точности позиционирования на экранах с высоким разрешением.